# If you have two verbs governed by he/she/it, does the second verb also need to be singular of only the first one?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

When you use *he, she*, or *it* in a sentence, you need to modify the verb for the third person singular, but what happens if we use two or more verbs in the same sentence? Example:

1. The thief steals and **runs**.
2. The thief steals and **run**.

Which of those is the right sentence? English is not my native language, so I am still learning things.

Comment: This should be in the ELL part of the site. Anyway, the verbs agree with the subject: steals and runs. Just as in Spanish, Italian etc. The verbs always agree with the subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plural / singular verbs need to agree with the plural / singular subjects.

> The thief steals and runs.
>   The thieves steal and run.
>
> The thief steals and *(the thief)* runs.
>   The thieves steal and *(the thieves)* run.